# NAs introduced by coercion - but no NAs listing in output

Tags: r

After running the following code I receive the warning message "NAs introduced by coercion", but when I check the output, there are no NAs:

```
#remove the records with missing values from the dataset
Data <- na.omit(Data)
#how many missing values in total are there?
summary(Data)
#Library call
library(cluster)
#convert the Gower dissimilarity object into a distance matrix
as.matrix(dist(Data))
Dist <- as.matrix(Dist)
```

Sample result:

```
1 2 3 4
1 0.000000e+00 951.77066 1351.64209 166.89518
5 6 7 8 9
1 1.352908e+02 258.11690 51088.23 2212.0103 515.47992
10 11 12 13
1 2367.57026 1.217035e+02 340.10330 330.23676
14 15 16 17
1 4405.2212 3.313772e+02 193.60513 3.168459e+02
18 19 20 21
1 422.42520 3.301973e+02 174.90726 1972.93727
22 23 24 25
1 160.52936 2084.11335 137.17138 9.516972e+01
26 27 28 29
1 168.36518 3.319189e+02 335.60344 3.331150e+02
```

Why does the warning appear if there are no NAs present in the output?

Comment: It doesn't say that you have NA's, but that NA's were introduced. Exactly why is hard to figure out without a reproducible example, we don't have your `Data`.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a sample of the input data that was used:                                  b,30.83,0,u,g,w,v,1.25,t,t,01,f,g,00202,0,+
a,58.67,4.46,u,g,q,h,3.04,t,t,06,f,g,00043,560,+
a,24.50,0.5,u,g,q,h,1.5,t,f,0,f,g,00280,824,+
b,27.83,1.54,u,g,w,v,3.75,t,t,05,t,g,00100,3,+
b,20.17,5.625,u,g,w,v,1.71,t,f,0,f,s,00120,0,+
b,32.08,4,u,g,m,v,2.5,t,f,0,t,g,00360,0,+
b,33.17,1.04,u,g,r,h,6.5,t,f,0,t,g,00164,31285,+
a,22.92,11.585,u,g,cc,v,0.04,t,f,0,f,g,00080,1349,+
b,54.42,0.5,y,p,k,h,3.96,t,f,0,f,g,00180,314,+
b,42.50,4.915,y,p,w,v,3.165,t,f,0,t,g,00052,1442,+

Comment: Should I ignore the warning? The data was supplied.

Comment: I think I know why I am getting this message, I just don't know what to do next:           
#Check for NAs
str(Data)

Sample result:

'data.frame': 653 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ Age               : num  30.8 58.7 24.5 27.8 20.2 ...
 $ MonthlyExpenses   : int  0 4 0 1 5 4 1 11 0 4 ...
 $ MaritalStatus     : Factor w/ 3 levels "l","u","y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ HomeStatus        : Factor w/ 3 levels "g","gg","p": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...

Comment: I believe it's the values like "g","gg","p" that's throwing it......... so is there a way around this?  Do I just suppress the warning?  Or do I need to fix this?